# MSMQ - performance test / stress load on server with few workstations

Tags: performance, msmq, stress-testing

I am trying to run some MSMQ performance test on a Win2008r2 server. Ideally, I would like to simulate several thousands of workstations sending (each of them) 5 msgs/sec.

One way to do so is to work with Amazon but I am wondering if this could be done in other ways.

I taught that using a custom tool which sends a large number of msgs on a single workstation could do the job but it seems that they are some internal mechanisms which affects a true real life representation of what I am trying to simulate. I can send 2000msgs/sec on a workstation but because of the OUTGOING queue and other mechanism, the server seems to swallow the whole things in large chunks of data (and I am noticing only, at best,  50msgs/sec peaks)

I believe there must be some kind of overhead operation from the workstation before sending data to server which I loose by simulating only a single workstation (or a few more).

Any ideas ?

P.S. I am using a private transactional queue. Win7 on workstation. MSMQ 5

Answer (score 3):

Simulating throughput is easy but it is incredibly hard to simulate multiple MSMQ clients. Each client has a unique IP address and it's own client-queue-manager-to-server-queue-manager network connection. Using Amazon to generate a large number of instances of a Windows client would do the trick but I haven't seen any solution that works on standard PCs.

The overhead you can't simulate with just sending lots of messages is the kernel memory used by the network connection and the threads used to handle incoming messages. Network connections are very expensive and eventually the server will fail if you have too many simultaneously connected clients.

As you are continuously sending messages, each client will have a persistent connection to the server. This is good for speed but bad for memory/thread usage. 5,000 clients will require a powerful 64-bit server.

[So, what's the limit on connections to an MSMQ server?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2007/02/15/so-what-s-the-limit-on-connections-to-an-msmq-server.aspx)

["What are MSMQ's limits?" If I had a farthing for every time...](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/02/29/what-are-msmq-s-limits-if-i-had-a-farthing-for-every-time.aspx)

[Insufficient Resources? Run away, run away!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2006/09/18/insufficient-resources-run-away-run-away.aspx)

[FIX: Kernel-pool memory may become exhausted when many clients connect to Message Queuing](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;870985)